# sqlite3 rowid alias not being properly created

Tags: python, sqlite

According to the [sqlite3 documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), creating a table where the primary key is an ascending integer causes the primary key to be an alias for the rowID. This isn't happening for me.

Here is my creation code:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/emaildb.sqlite3")
c = con.cursor()
try:
    c.execute("create table drives (driveid integer primary key asc, drivename text unique);")
    con.commit()
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    pass
```

Here is my checking code:

```
try:
    c.execute("insert into drives (drivename) values (?)",(drivename,))
    print "new ID=",c.lastrowid
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    c.execute("select rowid from drives where drivename=?",(drivename,))
    driveid = c.fetchone()[0]
    print "old ID=",driveid
```

This works if I `select rowid` but not if I `select driveid`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

I am not familiar with the "asc" directive in your create-table.